# The $I$-adic topology of $N$ coincides with the topology induced by the $I$-adic of $M$ on the subspace $N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I'm having trouble understanding the proof for the following proposition.

> Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring, $M$ a finite $A$-module, $N\subset M$ a
>   submodule, $I$ an ideal of $A$. Then the $I$-adic topology of $N$
>   coincides with the topology induced by the $I$-adic of $M$ on the
>   subspace $N$.

So I get that the I-adic topology on $N$ is $\mathcal{B}_1=\{I^nN\}_{n=1,2,...}$ and the topology induced by the $I$-adic topology of $M$ on $N$ is $\mathcal{B}_2=\{I^nM\cap N\}_{n=1,2,...}$.

So I guess I need to show, that taking $B_1\in \mathcal{B}_1$ and $b_1\in B_1$ we have to find $B_2\in \mathcal{B}_2$ such that $b_1\in B_2$ and $B_2\subset B_1$ (and vice versa)?

Now the proof for the proposition states, that it follows from the Artin-Rees lemma since $I^nN\subset I^nM\cap N\subset I^{n-c}N$. Now I see this would imply that $B_2\subset B_1$ (and vice versa) if we use the notation above, but doesn't we also need to show that there exist elements $b_1$ which is in $B_2$ (and vice versa)?
Meaning we need som element say $r_1\in I^nM\cap N$ which is also in $I^nN$, and some element $r_2\in I^{n-c}N$ which is also in $I^nM\cap N$?

Also, I'm not sure of the inclusions $I^nN\subset I^nM\cap N\subset I^{n-c}N$. My guess for the last inclusions follows from the fact that $I^nM\cap N=I^{n-c}(I^cM\cap N)\subset I^{n-c}N$ since $I^cM\cap N\subset N$, is that correct? For the first inclusion I'd say that it follows from the fact that  $I^nN\subset AN=N$ and $I^nN\subset I^nM$?

Comment: Perhaps what is going on is that the neighborhoods $\{I^n N\}$ (and their translates!) are a basis for the topology, and hence they are not all of the open sets in the topology (and ditto for $I^n M \cap N$). Think of a similar situation: one can generate the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$  with open disks or squares; no open disk actually equals a square, but for any square you can fit a disk inside it, and vice versa, showing that these two bases generate the same topology.

Comment: The sequences you describe are not the two topologies, but rather, bases at identity. What you need to show is that for every $n$, there is some $m$ such that $I^nN\supseteq I^mM\cap N$ and $I^nM\cap N\supseteq I^mN$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(In this post $A\subset B$ and $B\supset A$ mean that $A$ is a subset of $B$.)

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with one, $I$ an ideal, $M$ a module, $N$ a submodule, $\mathcal N$ the set of neighborhoods of $0$ for the $I$-adic topology of $N$, and $\mathcal N'$ the set of neighborhoods of $0$ for the topology on $N$ induced by the $I$-adic topology of $M$.

The inclusion $\mathcal N'\subset\mathcal N$ is easily verified.

Consider the conditions

$(1)\ \exists a\in\mathbb N,\ \forall b\in\mathbb N\ \Big(I^b(N\cap I^aM)=N\cap I^{a+b}M\Big),$

$(2)\ \forall b\in\mathbb N,\ \exists a\in\mathbb N\ \Big(I^bN\supset N\cap I^{a+b}M\Big),$

$(3)\ \mathcal N\subset\mathcal N'$.

Clearly $(1)$ implies $(2)$.

Claim: $(2)$ implies $(3)$.

Proof: Let $X$ be in $\mathcal N$. Then $X\supset I^bN$ for some $b$, and we get 
$$
X\supset I^bN\supset N\cap I^{a+b}M\
$$ 
for some $a$, and thus $X\in \mathcal N'$.

Answer (score 1):

See Corollary 10.10 in Atiyah Macdonald. This follows from the Artin--Rees lemma:

> Let $I$ be an ideal in a Noetherian ring $R$; let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module and let $N$ a submodule of $M$. Then there exists an integer $k \geqslant 1$ so that $ I^nM\cap N=I^{n-k}((I^kM)\cap N)$ for each $n\geqslant k$.

One can find this statement and a proof in, say, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Rees_lemma).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/992524)

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am not providing a link, but rather a reference. This answer is not becoming invalid any soon unless every single copy of AM in the world is lost. Probably that won't happen. ;)

Comment: Your answer came through the review queue.  It is a bare reference devoid of any context or explanation.  I clicked on the canned "Link Only" response, which automatically generated the text you see.  In this case, I might have preferred the final sentence to read "It should not be assumed that everyone has access to any particular book, or to an academic library which possesses this text.  It would be better to provide a self-contained answer and outline the result."  Aside from that, I stand by my decision to recommend deletion.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: When you voted to delete you don't have to provide a reason. (I agree that this answer should be a comment).

Comment: @JohnMa Perhaps, but the "Link Only" canned response seemed about right.  Lacking the ability to give more precise feedback, it seemed rude not to at least provide some justification.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Well, the "link only" comment always provide confusions when the answer has no link (especially that last sentence). I think either you write a comment (or make a generic one for this situation) if you have time, or you don't comment at all.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am trusting the OP can ask further questions if need be. For the moment I pasted the statement of the Artin--Rees lemma, that is what the OP wants.